# Make multiple pipe with waiting for return code of each process

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork, dup

I want to reproduce the pipe system of UNIX Shell in C using **execve**, **dup2**, **fork**, **waitpid** & **pipe** functions.

Right, for example this command : `/bin/ls -l | /usr/bin/head -2 | /usr/bin/wc` is reproduced by :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int add_child_process(char **argv, int in, int out, char **envp)
{
  int pid;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
    {
      if (in != 0)
    {
      dup2(in, 0);
    }
      if (out != 1)
    {
      dup2(out, 1);
    }
      if (execve(argv[0], argv, envp) == -1)
        perror("Execve failed");
    }
  else
    return (pid);


}

int main(int av, char **ag, char **envp)
{
  int in;
  int pipes[2];
  char *argv[3];
  int pids[3];

  /** Launch first process that read on original stdin (0) and write on out of pipe **/
  pipe(pipes);
  argv[0] = "/bin/ls";
  argv[1] = "-l";
  argv[2] = NULL;
  pids[0] = add_child_process(argv, 0, pipes[1], envp);
  close(pipes[1]);
  in = pipes[0];

  /** Launch second process that read on in of old pipe and write on out of new pipe **/
  pipe(pipes);
  argv[0] = "/usr/bin/head";
  argv[1] = "-2";
  argv[2] = NULL;
  pids[1] = add_child_process(argv, in, pipes[1], envp);
  close(in);
  close(pipes[1]);
  in = pipes[0];

  /** Launch last process that read on in of old pipe and write on original stdout (1) **/
  argv[0] = "/usr/bin/wc";
  argv[1] = NULL;
  pids[2] = add_child_process(argv, in, 1, envp);
  close(in);

  /** Wait for all process end to catch all return codes **/
  int return_code;
  waitpid(pids[0], &return_code, 0);
  printf("Process 0 return : %d\n", return_code);
  waitpid(pids[1], &return_code, 0);
  printf("Process 1 return : %d\n", return_code);
  waitpid(pids[2], &return_code, 0);
  printf("Process 2 return : %d\n", return_code);
}
```

Work, the output is :

```
2      11      60
Process 0 return : 0
Process 1 return : 0
Process 2 return : 0
```

Like `echo "/bin/ls -l | /usr/bin/head -2 | /usr/bin/wc" | bash`

But for blocking command like `ping google.com | head -2 | wc` it's show this :

```
      2      16     145
```

and remains blocked.

Here is updated main with this command :

```
int main(int av, char **ag, char **envp)
{
  int in;
  int pipes[2];
  char *argv[3];
  int pids[3];

  /** Launch first process that read on original in (0) and write on out of pipe **/
  pipe(pipes);
  argv[0] = "/bin/ping";
  argv[1] = "google.com";
  argv[2] = NULL;
  pids[0] = add_child_process(argv, 0, pipes[1], envp);
  close(pipes[1]);
  in = pipes[0];

  /** Launch second process that read on in of old pipe and write on out of new pipe **/
  pipe(pipes);
  argv[0] = "/usr/bin/head";
  argv[1] = "-2";
  argv[2] = NULL;
  pids[1] = add_child_process(argv, in, pipes[1], envp);
  close(in);
  close(pipes[1]);
  in = pipes[0];

  /** Launch last process that read on in of old pipe and write on original stdout (1) **/
  argv[0] = "/usr/bin/wc";
  argv[1] = NULL;
  pids[2] = add_child_process(argv, in, 1, envp);
  close(in);

  /** Wait for all process end to catch all return codes **/
  int return_code;
  waitpid(pids[0], &return_code, 0);
  printf("Process 0 return : %d\n", return_code);
  waitpid(pids[1], &return_code, 0);
  printf("Process 1 return : %d\n", return_code);
  waitpid(pids[2], &return_code, 0);
  printf("Process 2 return : %d\n", return_code);
}
```

I really don't understand why this behaviour occur for example in Bash : `echo "ping google.com | head -2 | wc" | bash` show `2      16   145` and don't stuck.

How I can deal with blocking command ? I need to get all return codes of my process for make return according to the last error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add_child_process()` function is supposed to return the PID; it doesn't.  It should also have error handling after the `execve()` in case the program fails to execute.

#### First solution — not good enough

With those fixed (and sundry other changes to get past my minimum level of compilation warnings — such as `#include <stdio.h>` so that there's a declaration for `printf()` before it is used), I get roughly the expected output.

I used this code (source file `pc67.c`) to test:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static
int add_child_process(char **argv, int in, int out, char **envp)
{
    int pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (in != 0)
        {
            dup2(in, 0);
        }
        if (out != 1)
        {
            dup2(out, 1);
        }
        execve(argv[0], argv, envp);
        abort();
    }
    return pid;
}

int main(int av, char **ag, char **envp)
{
    int in;
    int pipes[2];
    char *argv[3];
    int pids[3];
    assert(ag[av] == 0);

    /** Launch first process that read on original stdin (0) and write on out of pipe **/
    pipe(pipes);
    argv[0] = "/bin/ls";
    argv[1] = "-l";
    argv[2] = NULL;
    pids[0] = add_child_process(argv, 0, pipes[1], envp);
    close(pipes[1]);
    in = pipes[0];

    /** Launch second process that read on in of old pipe and write on out of new pipe **/
    pipe(pipes);
    argv[0] = "/usr/bin/head";
    argv[1] = "-2";
    argv[2] = NULL;
    pids[1] = add_child_process(argv, in, pipes[1], envp);
    close(in);
    close(pipes[1]);
    in = pipes[0];

    /** Launch last process that read on in of old pipe and write on original stdout (1) **/
    argv[0] = "/usr/bin/wc";
    argv[1] = NULL;
    pids[2] = add_child_process(argv, in, 1, envp);
    close(in);

    /** Wait for all process end to catch all return codes **/
    int return_code;
    waitpid(pids[0], &return_code, 0);
    printf("Process 0 return : %d\n", return_code);
    waitpid(pids[1], &return_code, 0);
    printf("Process 1 return : %d\n", return_code);
    waitpid(pids[2], &return_code, 0);
    printf("Process 2 return : %d\n", return_code);
}
```

The `abort()` didn't fire; the commands all executed (I did check that they were in the directories you listed before trying to run the code).

I compile on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 using GCC 6.3.0 with the command line:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition pc67.c -o pc67
$
```

With that, I get the output:

```
$ ./pc67
       2      11      70
Process 0 return : 0
Process 1 return : 0
Process 2 return : 0
$
```

The 11 words are 'total' and the number of blocks, and then 9 words for one line of the `ls -l` output.  I've rerun checking the output from `ps` before and after the command; there are no stray processes running.

#### Second solution — circumvention and not cure

> Thanks, but unlike Bash `echo "ping google.com | head -2 | wc" | bash`, it is still blocked in a wait and doesn't terminate the program.

I'm not clear what your alternative command line has to do with your question.  However, there are a number of things that could be going on when you introduce `ping google.com` instead of `ls -l` as the command.  You can't legitimately change the parameters of your question like that.  It's a new question altogether.

In the shell surrogate, you've not specified paths to the programs; your code won't handle that. (If you use `execvp()` instead of `execve()` — using `execve()` when you're simply relaying the inherited environment is pointless; the environment is inherited anyway — then the paths to the commands would be irrelevant).

However, using `"/sbin/ping"` and `"google.com"` (in a copy of the program `pc23.c`) does seem to hang.  Looking at the setup from another terminal, I see:

```
$ ps -ftttys000
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0 51551 51550   0 10:13AM ttys000    0:00.50 login -pf jleffler
  502 51553 51551   0 10:13AM ttys000    0:00.14 -bash
  502 54866 51553   0 11:10AM ttys000    0:00.01 pc23
  502 54867 54866   0 11:10AM ttys000    0:00.00 /sbin/ping google.com
  502 54868 54866   0 11:10AM ttys000    0:00.00 (head)
  502 54869 54866   0 11:10AM ttys000    0:00.00 (wc)
$
```

Both the `head` and the `wc` processes have terminated (those are the entries for zombies), but the `ping` process isn't dying.  It doesn't seem to be doing much, but it isn't dying either.

Some time later, I got:

```
$ ps -ftttys000
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
    0 51551 51550   0 10:13AM ttys000    0:00.50 login -pf jleffler
  502 51553 51551   0 10:13AM ttys000    0:00.14 -bash
  502 54866 51553   0 11:10AM ttys000    0:00.01 pc23
  502 54867 54866   0 11:10AM ttys000    0:00.09 /sbin/ping google.com
  502 54868 54866   0 11:10AM ttys000    0:00.00 (head)
  502 54869 54866   0 11:10AM ttys000    0:00.00 (wc)
$
```

It's managed to use 9 CPU seconds.  So, in this context, for some reason, `ping` doesn't pay attention to the `SIGPIPE` signal.

How to fix?  That requires experimentation and could be more intricate.  The easiest fix is to add options such as `-c` and `3` — that worked for me.  I don't immediately have an incentive to go looking for alternative fixes.

The macOS man page for `ping` says, in part:

> `-c count`
>
> Stop after sending (and receiving) *count* ECHO_RESPONSE packets.  If this option is not specified, `ping` will operate until interrupted.  If this option is specified in conjunction with `ping` sweeps, each sweep will consist of *count* packets.

It is intriguing to speculate how precise the term 'interrupted' is.  The program terminates if sent an actual (<kbd>Control-C</kbd>) interrupt, or a `SIGTERM` signal (`kill 54867`).  It is curious that it sometimes stops on `SIGPIPE` and sometimes does not.

#### Third solution — close the file descriptors

On further thought, the problem is that the code is not closing enough file descriptors.  That's most often the problem with pipelines not terminating.  With `ls` as the first process, the problem is hidden because `ls` terminates automatically, closing the stray file descriptors.
Changing to `ping` exposes the problems.  Here's another revision of the code.  It closes the `dup2()` descriptors (oops; slap self on wrist).  It also ensures that the other pipe descriptor is closed via the new `tbc` (to be closed) file descriptor argument to `add_child_process()`.  I've also opted to use `execv()` instead of `execve()`, removing one argument from the `add_child_process()` function, and allowing `int main(void)` since the program pays no attention to its arguments (which allows me to lose the `assert()`, which was there to 'ensure' that the argument count and vector arguments were 'used', as long as you didn't compile with `-DNDEBUG` or equivalent).

I also tweaked the command-building code so that it was easy to add/remove the `-c` and `3` arguments from `ping`, or to add/remove arguments from other commands.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static
int add_child_process(char **argv, int in, int out, int tbc)
{
    int pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (tbc >= 0)
            close(tbc);
        if (in != 0)
        {
            dup2(in, 0);
            close(in);
        }
        if (out != 1)
        {
            dup2(out, 1);
            close(out);
        }
        execv(argv[0], argv);
        abort();
    }
    return pid;
}

int main(void)
{
    int in;
    int pipes[2];
    char *argv[10];
    int pids[3];

    /** Launch first process that read on original stdin (0) and write on out of pipe **/
    pipe(pipes);
    int argn = 0;
    argv[argn++] = "/sbin/ping";
    //argv[argn++] = "-c";
    //argv[argn++] = "3";
    argv[argn++] = "google.com";
    argv[argn++] = NULL;
    pids[0] = add_child_process(argv, 0, pipes[1], pipes[0]);
    close(pipes[1]);
    in = pipes[0];

    /** Launch second process that read on in of old pipe and write on out of new pipe **/
    pipe(pipes);
    argn = 0;
    argv[argn++] = "/usr/bin/head";
    argv[argn++] = "-2";
    argv[argn++] = NULL;
    pids[1] = add_child_process(argv, in, pipes[1], pipes[0]);
    close(in);
    close(pipes[1]);
    in = pipes[0];

    /** Launch last process that read on in of old pipe and write on original stdout (1) **/
    argn = 0;
    argv[argn++] = "/usr/bin/wc";
    argv[argn++] = NULL;
    pids[2] = add_child_process(argv, in, 1, -1);
    close(in);

    /** Wait for all process end to catch all return codes **/
    int return_code;
    waitpid(pids[0], &return_code, 0);
    printf("Process 0 return : %d\n", return_code);
    waitpid(pids[1], &return_code, 0);
    printf("Process 1 return : %d\n", return_code);
    waitpid(pids[2], &return_code, 0);
    printf("Process 2 return : %d\n", return_code);
}
```

With this code (executable `pc73` built from `pc73.c`), I get output like:

```
$ ./pc73
       2      14     109
Process 0 return : 13
Process 1 return : 0
Process 2 return : 0
$
```

There's a short, sub-second pause between the output from `wc` appearing and the other output; the `ping` command waits a second before trying to write again.  The exit status of `13` indicates `ping` did die from a `SIGPIPE` signal.  The previous problem was that `ping` still had the read end of the pipe open, so it didn't get the `SIGPIPE` signal.

#### Lesson to be learned — close lots of file descriptors

When working with pipes, make sure you're closing all the file descriptors you need to close.

Comment: Thank's, but unlike Bash `echo "ping google.com | head -2 | wc" | bash` It is still blocked in a wait and don't terminate program [Screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/f41dd38a3dbd46448b2b53b764659f1f.png)

Comment: Yeah when the first process is /bin/ls it's work like Bash, but when it's /bin/ping it didn't work (like my second example).

Comment: See my updated answer.  Note that I changed the definition of `argv` to `char *argv[10];` before adding extra arguments to `ping`.  I wasn't sure if I'd need to use more arguments in the long run (5 would be enough).

Comment: Perfect explanation, great ! 
If I understood correctly when I run my processes one by one connected by a pipe, when the *head* received 2 lines in his stdin he send a *SIGPIPE* to the *ping* to terminate it ? And so when it catch his waitpid function, why status is 0 and not a status like *SIGPIPE* signal ?

Comment: A process gets a `SIGPIPE` signal when it tries to write on a pipe for which there is no reader process.  So, after `head` exits, you would expect `ping` to get a `SIGPIPE` when it tries to write to the pipe.  It's possible to ignore `SIGPIPE`; then the `write()` calls returns `-1` and sets `errno` to a suitable value (`EPIPE` — 'broken pipe').  But maybe `ping` isn't paying proper attention to the error.

Comment: Right I understand thanks, I have an other strange behaviour with *echo "man gcc | cat | ls" | tcsh* in TCSH it's don't stuck, but with my program it is [screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/50982559af8e42cbb129e95e0ebf29ea.png) It seem to be a broken pipe (shell return 141), how I can handle this error like TCSH do and avoid infinite wait in my program ?

Comment: I need to amend my answer — not enough file descriptors are being closed.  Back in 15 minutes or maybe more.

Comment: It seems it took me just under 20 minutes to get the information into shape.  The code shown in 'Third Solution' takes `ping | head -n 2 | wc` (with paths still required) and it works as you'd expect/want.  Check your `tcsh` problem — it likely is also fixed.

Comment: Very interesting as an answer. In fact you have to close the file descriptor even in the fork? I thought that at the end of the execve the process was killed and the fd closed on its own. And why in the end the -1 for `add_child_process(argv, in, 1, -1, envp);` ?

Comment: That was the trouble for `ping`; it still had the read end of the pipe open, so it wasn't getting the SIGPIPE because there was a process (the same process) that could, in theory, read from the pipe. It was never going to do so, but the o/s doesn't know that the process doesn't know about the file descriptors it has open. So, it assumes it will read from the pipe. And eventually, the `ping` would have filled the pipe and would have then blocked indefinitely waiting for itself to read from the pipe while it was stuck trying to write to it — a livelock scenario. I should've paid more attention.